# Cannot restore to the last activity after close the app

Tags: android

My app has 4 activities: SplashActivity, LoginActivity, ActivityA and ActivityB.

The ActivityB is started from the ActivityA.

The SplashActivity is my app launcher. It will check if a user is logged in to start ActivityA else ActivityA.

My problem is when I am in ActivityB and then close the app by pressing the home button. When I open the app again it opens ActivityA which is not as my expectation. It should open ActivityB.

Manifest:

```
       <activity
            android:name=".screen.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="${splashTheme}"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityB"
            android:exported="false"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name="LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="${splashTheme}" />
        <activity
```

Here is the SplashActivity logic:

```
            if (SettingService.isLogged()) {
                val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, ActivityA::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                startActivity<LoginActivity>() // org.jetbrains.anko
            }
```

Comment: Please share the logic that happens in your SplashActivity. There might be something there that is not routing to the activity you think.

Comment: "It will check if a user is logged in to start ActivityA else ActivityA." Please share the code of this logic